# How to test that my stacktrace walker correctly skips library code

Tags: c#, unit-testing, exception

My question is:  I am trying to skip some stackframes that come from library code. If I want to test this, how do I best/easiest force a situation where the stacktrace has one or more frames on top that come from library code?

**Details:**

My goal with the code below is to be able to log the origin of an exception in my source code. However, in some cases the exception is triggered in library code, so I get a stacktrace that looks like this:

> System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out
>          at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
>          at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
>          at Microsoft.Bing.Platform.ConversationalUnderstanding.ObjectStore.ObjectStoreClientHelperClass.d__7``2.MoveNext()
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>          at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>          at Microsoft.Bing.Platform.ConversationalUnderstanding.ObjectStore.ObjectStoreCoprocRequest.d__10`4.MoveNext()
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

So basically I want to move on down the stackframes until I hit a spot where I have actual useful information, skipping the library methods that don't really tell me anything useful.

Here's the code I want to test:

```
public static (string Path, string Method, int Line) TryGetExceptionOrigin(this Exception e, string defaultPath, string defaultMethod, int defaultLine)
{
    var defaultRes = (Path: defaultPath, Method: defaultMethod, Line: defaultLine);
    var st = new StackTrace(e.GetInnerMostException(), true);
    if (st.FrameCount == 0)
    {
        return defaultRes;
    }

    // Walk down the stack, ignoring framework code etc. with no useful information. We need a file name to be happy
    for (int i = 0; i < st.FrameCount; i++)
    {
        var bottomFrame = st.GetFrame(i);
        if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(bottomFrame.GetFileName())))
        {
            return (
            Path: bottomFrame.GetFileName() ?? string.Empty, // Is null if no debug information
            Method: bottomFrame.GetMethod().Name, // Documentation does not say this can ever be null
            Line: bottomFrame.GetFileLineNumber()); // Is 0 if no debug information
        }
    }

    // OK no match, we return the default information
    return defaultRes;
}
```

Comment: send a malformed request to the ASP.NET or WCF pipeline. those are famous for their multilayered exception stacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it at https://dotnetthoughts.wordpress.com/2007/10/27/where-did-my-exception-occur/

```
    private static void ThrowIt()
    {
        Divide(3M, 0M);
    }

    static decimal Divide(decimal a, decimal b)
    {
        return (a / b);
    }
```

This will produce this stacktrace:

> st    {
>   at System.Decimal.FCallDivide(Decimal& d1, Decimal& d2)
>   at System.Decimal.op_Division(Decimal d1, Decimal d2)
>   at ExceptionLogging.Program.Divide(Decimal a, Decimal b) in C:\Users\anjohans\source\repos\ExceptionLogging\ExceptionLogging\Program.cs:line
>   98    at ExceptionLogging.Program.ThrowIt() in
>   C:\Users\anjohans\source\repos\ExceptionLogging\ExceptionLogging\Program.cs:line
>   93    at ExceptionLogging.Program.ThrowLater() in
>   C:\Users\anjohans\source\repos\ExceptionLogging\ExceptionLogging\Program.cs:line
>   88    at ExceptionLogging.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   C:\Users\anjohans\source\repos\ExceptionLogging\ExceptionLogging\Program.cs:line
>   17 }  System.Diagnostics.StackTrace

Answer (score 0):

Some unnecessarily convoluted stuff like this should do nicely:

```
try
{
    Func<int> d = () =>
    {
        try
        {
            return Guid.Parse("*").ToByteArray()[0];
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    };
    Action a = () => { String.Format("{0}", 1 / d()); };
    a();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var useful = ex.TryGetExceptionOrigin(null, null, 0);
}
```

This example results in an exception call stack with three user code and four framework/library code entries.

Comment: Hmm, sorry no this will show as an anonymous function that is invokes in Main so not quite what I was looking for. Thanks though!